# GET http://localhost:3000/posts/timeline/(objId) 500 (Internal Server Error) - Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {'Request failed with status code 500'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
export default function Feed() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const PF = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_FOLDER;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("posts/timeline/628f04a81b8f4431e49b6679");
      console.log(res);
      setPosts(res.data);
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
```

On running this code I get these:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/posts/timeline/628f04a81b8f4431e49b6679 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:220
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:16
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:58
request @ Axios.js:109
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:131
wrap @ bind.js:9
fetchPosts @ Feed.jsx:13
(anonymous) @ Feed.jsx:17
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23049
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24816
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24781
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24768
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24756
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26990
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26935
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26725
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

This is the first error that the system is not able to fetch data. I am stuck here for a while. I am entirely new to react so if anyone can solve this and explain as if you are explaining to a baby would be great. I will be able to understand it more easily then. Thank you

```
Feed.jsx:16 Uncaught (in promise) 
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
message: "Request failed with status code 500"
name: "AxiosError"
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response: {data: {…}, status: 500, statusText: 'Internal Server Error', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
[[Prototype]]: Error
fetchPosts  @   Feed.jsx:16
await in fetchPosts (async)     
(anonymous) @   Feed.jsx:17
commitHookEffectListMount   @   react-dom.development.js:23049
commitPassiveMountOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:24816
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete  @   react-dom.development.js:24781
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @   react-dom.development.js:24768
commitPassiveMountEffects   @   react-dom.development.js:24756
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @   react-dom.development.js:26990
flushPassiveEffects @   react-dom.development.js:26935
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:26725
workLoop    @   scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork   @   scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline    @   scheduler.development.js:533
```

and this is the axios error that I get

Comment: Since it is a `500` you should post the backend code also

Answer (score 0):

open your dev tools then go to network and delete the users log for example GET http://localhost:3000/posts/timeline/628f04a81b8f4431e49b6679 delete that users and it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).